# Exim forwards not going out through TLS

Tags: exim, tls

I'm trying to get Exim to use STARTTLS to send emails that are just FORWARDS.

I have a server accepting email at example-accepting.com for users. So I want user@example-accepting.com to forward all email to user@example.com.
If I do this from the command like on example-accepting.com...
echo "test" | mail -s  "ssl/tls test" user@example.com
Success!! Sent via TLS
BUT, if I send an email to user@example-accepting.com the forward fails, it's NOT being sent via TLS. I've tried both forwarding the email via /etc/aliases and the user .forward file. The email is indeed sent, but NOT via TLS.

Why is it when I run "mail" from the command like it's working like it should, but a .forward is not using TLS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting `hosts_require_tls` to include the domain you are forwarding to.  This should cause Exim to always use TLS for the server.  This may need to be set on all transports using the smtp driver.  (Some configurations have multiple smtp transports.)

EDIT: If it works from the command line, then your configuration appears correct.  It is possible that your running daemon is running an old configuration.  You could test this with a command like

```
sendmail -odq -fyou@example.com you@example.com
Subject: Test message

test
.
```

This should add the message to the queue.  It will be delivered the next time the queue is run.   Check that message to see if it as delivered using TLS.  You can get Exim to reload its configuration by sending it a `HUP` signal.  The command `exiwhat` should tell you the PID of the Exim daemon.

Comment: Wouldn't this do it?
in 
/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp
 I have  hosts_require_tls = *

Comment: Also, it *is* using TLS from the command line, but it's not when the email is send via /etc/alisases or a .forward file.

Comment: It is possible another transport is handling the request.  Try setting hosts_require_tls at the top of the configuration.  It should apply to all transports when set there.

Comment: No, `hosts_require_tls` is an SMTP Transport option, it needs to be set on a particular transport, it can not be set in the main section of the configuration. There are no general rules that Transport options can be set in Main.

Answer (score 0):

You have some kind of constraint on which router can be used, which is being applied based on some local configuration.  Perhaps you set some `$acl_m_foo` data in an ACL which is later evaluated in a router, perhaps the relevant router is checking `$sender_host_address`.

Use `exim -bt user@example.com` to see how Exim normally routes mails to that address, and use `exim -bh 192.0.2.4 -bt user@example.com` to see the decisions made when Exim assumes that the message was sent from `192.0.2.4`.  To see more data, use the `-d` option, for debugging, which also takes a bunch of tags to turn on even more debugging (eg, `-d+expand+acl`).

In a normal configuration, routers only look at the recipient, not the sender, so if recipient A is routed such that TLS is used for a mail submitted locally, it will do so if the message came in remotely. Exim is powerful and flexible enough that you can shoot yourself in the foot, though.